# Where does WordPress store a list of Super Admins?

Tags: admin

I had to switch around my Super Admins. I did it through the MySQL tables directly.

I now have 1 official Super Admin for my network (which is what I want & need) but WordPress shows that I have 2 Super Admins:

```
All (71) | Super Admins (2)
```

Where does WP store the SA count or the list of SA's?

Answer (score 3):

It's stored in the main site options table, under the "site_admins" key.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the "site options" table in multisite is actually named PREFIX_sitemeta, like "wp_sitemeta". It's referred to as a site option internally, like `get_site_option('site_admins')`.

To adjust this without editing the database content directly, you could do this:

```
$capes = get_site_option('site_admins');
// $capes is an array of the super admin usernames, adjust it as needed
// then save it back like so:
set_site_option('site_admins', $capes);
```

Comment: Then you don't have any super-admins. ;) That is the *only* place the list of super admins is stored. Make sure you're checking the SITE options table, not just the options table for one of the individual blogs.

Comment: It's not in `{$prefix}_options` in my test installation; it's in `{$prefix}_sitemeta`.

Comment: Yes, okay, sitemeta then. In the WordPress code, this is called site_options. Stupid terminology.

Answer (score 2):

On SQL level, you can find in `site_admins` key in `wp_sitemeta` table. Check the `meta_value` key for find out who is Super Admin in your installation.